# R Optimization given objective function

Tags: r, optimization

```
obj1<-function(monthly.savings,
               success,
               start.capital,
               target.savings,
               monthly.mean.return,
               monthly.ret.std.dev,
               monthly.inflation,
               monthly.inf.std.dev,
               n.obs,
               n.sim=1000){

  req = matrix(start.capital, n.obs+1, n.sim) #matrix for storing target weight

  monthly.invest.returns = matrix(0, n.obs, n.sim)
  monthly.inflation.returns = matrix(0, n.obs, n.sim)

  monthly.invest.returns[] = rnorm(n.obs * n.sim, mean = monthly.mean.return, sd = monthly.ret.std.dev)
  monthly.inflation.returns[] = rnorm(n.obs * n.sim, mean = monthly.inflation, sd = monthly.inf.std.dev)

  #for loop to be 
  for (a in 1:n.obs){
    req[a + 1, ] = req[a, ] * (1 + monthly.invest.returns[a,] - monthly.inflation.returns[a,]) + monthly.savings
  }

  ending.values=req[nrow(req),]
  suc<-sum(ending.values>target.savings)/n.sim
  value<-success-suc

  return(abs(value))
}
```

I have the above objective function that I want to minimize for. It tries to solve for the monthly savings required for a given probability of success. Given the following input assumptions

```
success<-0.9
start.capital<-1000000
target.savings<-1749665
monthly.savings=10000
monthly.mean.return<-(5/100)/12
monthly.ret.std.dev<-(3/100)/sqrt(12)
monthly.inflation<-(5/100)/12
monthly.inf.std.dev<-(1.5/100)/sqrt(12)
monthly.withdrawals<-10000
n.obs<-10*12  #years * 12 months in a year
n.sim=1000
```

I used the following notation:

```
optimize(f=obj1,
        success=success,
        start.capital=start.capital,
        target.savings=target.savings,
        monthly.mean.return=monthly.mean.return,
        monthly.ret.std.dev=monthly.ret.std.dev,
        monthly.inflation=monthly.inflation,
        monthly.inf.std.dev=monthly.inf.std.dev,
        n.obs = n.obs,
        n.sim = n.sim,
        lower = 0,
        upper = 10000,
        tol = 0.000000001,maximum=F)
```

I get 7875.03

Since I am sampling from a normal distribution, the output will be different each time but they should be around the same give or take a few % points. The problem I am having is that I can't specify a upper limit arbitrarily. The above example's upper limit (10000) is cherry picked after numerous trials. If say I put in a upper limit of 100000 (unreasonable I know) it will return that number as oppose to finding the global minimum saving. Any ideas where I am structuring my objective function incorrectly?

thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that your function does not always return the same output for a given input
is likely to pose a few problems (it will create a lot of spurious local minima): 
you can avoid them by setting the seed of the random number generator
inside the function (e.g., `set.seed(1)`),
or by storing the random numbers and reusing them each time, 
or by using a low-discrepancy sequence (e.g., `randtoolbox::sobol`).

Since it is a function of one variable, you can simply plot it to see what happens:
it has a plateau after 10,000 -- optimization algorithms cannot distinguish 
between a plateau and a local optimum.

```
f <- function(x) {
  set.seed(1)
  obj1(x,
      success             = success,
      start.capital       = start.capital,
      target.savings      = target.savings,
      monthly.mean.return = monthly.mean.return,
      monthly.ret.std.dev = monthly.ret.std.dev,
      monthly.inflation   = monthly.inflation,
      monthly.inf.std.dev = monthly.inf.std.dev,
      n.obs               = n.obs,
      n.sim               = n.sim 
  )
}
g <- Vectorize(f)
curve(g(x), xlim=c(0, 20000))
```

Your initial problem is actually not a minimization problem, 
but a root finding problem, which is much easier.

```
obj2 <- function(monthly.savings) {
  set.seed(1)
  req = matrix(start.capital, n.obs+1, n.sim)
  monthly.invest.returns <- matrix(0, n.obs, n.sim)
  monthly.inflation.returns <- matrix(0, n.obs, n.sim)
  monthly.invest.returns[] <- rnorm(n.obs * n.sim, mean = monthly.mean.return, sd = monthly.ret.std.dev)
  monthly.inflation.returns[] <- rnorm(n.obs * n.sim, mean = monthly.inflation, sd = monthly.inf.std.dev)
  for (a in 1:n.obs)
    req[a + 1, ] <- req[a, ] * (1 + monthly.invest.returns[a,] - monthly.inflation.returns[a,]) + monthly.savings
  ending.values <- req[nrow(req),]
  suc <- sum(ending.values>target.savings)/n.sim
  success - suc
}
uniroot( obj2, c(0, 1e6) )
# [1] 7891.187
```